# Linq order by specific enum value

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have an IQueryable of objects

```
class Object
{
    int Id {get; set; }
    TypeEnum Type {get; set; }
    string Name {get; set; }
    bool IsMain {get; set; }
    bool Primary {get; set; }
}

enum TypeEnum
{
    a = 0,
    b = 1,
    c = 2
}
```

I need to order it like so:

1) Object with 'IsMain' set to true needs to be first (there is only 1)

2) Followed by Objects with 'Primary' set to true ordered by 'Name'

3) Followed by Objects with 'Type' set to 'b' ordered by 'Name'

4) Then the rest of Objects (types 'a' and 'c') ordered by name

How would I do that?
Is it possible to select all object with specific enum value and order them before the rest?

Comment: Please, share the example data and what you tried so far.`OrderBy`/`ThenBy` might help you

Comment: Did you try to use the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` extension methods? `objects.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsMain).ThenByDescending(x => x.Primary).ThenBy(x => x.Name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` to achieve this:

> 1) Object with 'IsMain' set to true needs to be first (there is only 1)

```
.OrderByDescending(o => o.IsMain) //Desc as true > false
```

> 2) Followed by Objects with 'Primary' set to true ordered by 'Name'

```
.ThenByDescending(o => o.IsPrimary) //Desc as true > false
```

> 3) Followed by Objects with 'Type' set to 'b' ordered by 'Name'

**This appears to be the main part of your question**

```
.ThenByDescending(o => o.Type == TypeEnum.b) //Desc as true > false
```

> 4) Then the rest of Objects (types 'a' and 'c') ordered by name

```
.ThenBy(o => o.Type)
```

I've made the assumption that name ordering is then the last priority after the above:

```
.ThenBy(o => o.Name)
```

Altogether:

```
var ordered = myObjects
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.IsMain)
    .ThenByDescending(o => o.IsPrimary)
    .ThenByDescending(o => o.Type == TypeEnum.b)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Type)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Name);
```

Comment: I found this answer helpful while trying to order paged data from SQL where the SQL table contained a Id value for an enumeration but I needed to sort by the text value of the enumeration. In particular this line provided the clue I needed, `.ThenByDescending(o => o.Type == TypeEnum.b)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implement a class with the Interface `IComparer<MyObject>`.

See [IComparer Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer?view=netframework-4.8) and [IComparer.Compare(Object, Object) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer.compare?view=netframework-4.8).

```
public class MyObjectComparer: IComparer<MyObject> {
    public int Compare(MyObject left, MyObject right) {

            if (left == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(left));
            }
            if (right == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(right));
            }

            // Object with 'IsMain' set to true needs to be first
            if (left.IsMain) {
                return right.IsMain ? 0 : 1;
            }
            if (right.IsMain) {
                return -1; // left.IsMain always false at this point
            }

            // Followed by Objects with 'Primary' set to true ordered by 'Name'
            if (left.Primary) {
                if (!right.Primary) { return 1; }
                return left.Name.CompareTo(right.Name);
            }
            if (right.Primary) {
                return -1; // left.Primary always false at this point
            }

            // Followed by Objects with 'Type' set to 'b' ordered by 'Name'
            if (left.Type == TypeEnum.b) {
                if (right.Type != TypeEnum.b) { return 1; }
                return left.Name.CompareTo(right.Name);
            }
            if (right.Type == TypeEnum.b) {
                return -1; // left.Type always != TypeEnum.b at this point
            }

            // Then the rest of Objects (types 'a' and 'c') ordered by name
             return left.Name.CompareTo(right.Name);
        }
}
```

You then can pass this comparer to the [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__) LINQ Method:

```
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<MyObject> allObjects;
var result = allObjects.OrderBy(o => o, new MyObjectComparer());
```

Note that this approach will not work for Linq2Sql, because the custom comparer can not be translated to SQL. In this case, enumerate the query and order it in memory.

```
var allObjects = _dbContext.MyObjects.ToArray(); // execute Linq2Sql and get objects into memory
var result = allObjects.OrderBy(o => o, new MyObjectComparer()); // now we can work with Linq2Entities with custom comparer
```

Comment: The problem is that his sequence is IQueryable instead of IEnumerable. This means that he can't use his own IComparer

Comment: One could use the workaround to enumerate the IQueryable and then order it in memory after it was fetched from the DB. This might not be feasable though if paging of the data is required. I will expand the example usage to reflect this.

Comment: I also edited the Compare Method to handle the cases `right.Primary == true` and `left.Primary == false`, as well as `right.Type == TypeEnum.b` and `left.Type != TypeEnum.b`.